# javascript outcome of toFixed().length

Tags: javascript

I have question about ".toFixed().length. I have here a if statement: if (num.toFixed(2).length > 4) {". And i dont understand the  outcome of the result.

i thougth it woud count the length of the string. Because toFixed covert the number to a string. But i dont get the outcome. I hope you have a ans because i cant find it on the internet or my teachers ad school dont know it ether. 
Thank you for your time,

```
num = 1234.567
>>> 1234.567

num2 = num.toFixed(2).length    
>>> 7 // why is this 7??

num2
>>> 7

num = 1234
>>> 1234

num2 = num.toFixed(2).length
>>> 7

num = 2
>>> 2

num2 = num.toFixed(2).length
>>> 4// and this 4??
```

Comment: `Number(1234.567).toFixed(2)` results in `"1234.57"`. That's 7 characters. I can't make out what your other questions are

Comment: You convert it to a string, so it counts the decimal point as well..... what @Phil said :D

Comment: Also `(2).toFixed(2)` results in the string "2.00" which has 4 characters, so length 4.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe in your question is essentially the expected behavior of `toFixed()`.

It will always round the passed number to two decimals and convert it to a string always showing these two decimals, even if they're 0.

You can try several [more results in this small sample on ideone](http://ideone.com/orxVpn).

---

Back to your initial question:

```
if (num.toFixed(2).length > 4)
```

This expression could be translated to "string representation is longer than 4 characters".

Since we already mentioned the two decimals and the decimal point always being there, all string results will end in `.##` (where `#` could be any digit). That's a string length of 3 characters.

This essentially means there have to be at least two more characters before the decimal point for this statement to become true:

`#.##` would be 4 characters, which still doesn't fulfill the condition.

'##.##' works. These are 5 characters, which is definitely longer than 4.

So this means any number equal to or bigger than 10 would fulfill this statement. Considering there's rounding involved, any number greater than `9.95` should work for this.

So why not write `if (num > 9.95)`? Simply because that's only part of the answer.

There are negative numbers as well. If you evaluate `Number(-1).toFixed(2)` you'll get the string `-1.00`, which is 5 characters already!

But what about rounding? Here it gets even more interesting. If you run `Number(-.01).toFixed(2)` one  would assume that this is rounded to `0.00`. This is kinda true, but JavaScript will retain the negative prefix, resulting in `-0.00`. This is once again a string with 5 characters!

So combining these two observations we can say that the expression in your `if()` clause is true under either of these two conditions:

- The number is bigger than 9.5 (i.e. it's rounded to 10 or larger)
- The number is negative.

So one could replace the rather cryptic/complicated expression with the following term and get the same results:

```
if (num < 0 || num >= 9.5)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
num = 1234.567
>>> 1234.567

num2 = num.toFixed(2).length    
>>> 7 // why is this 7??
```

Here you want to know the length of the string so it's giving you the string length. If you do `.tofixed(2)` on 1234.567 it will remain the same.